# Efficiency of acces to array in dll

Tags: c, arrays, winapi, optimization, dll

I gor an array/ram buffer

```
char* bitmap_bufer;
int bitmap_buffer_size_x;
int bitmap_buffer_size_y;
```

bitmap_buffer is mallocked (and is often reallocked to different 
sizes too), efficiency of acces to it contents is of absolutely TOP IMPORTANCE as i use it as a target to various rasterization/ per pixel drawing routines

bitmap_bufer[bitmap_buffer_size_x*y + x] = color; //etc

The question is if i move it to dll and import it in another module

```
__declspec(dllimport)     char* bitmap_bufer;
__declspec(dllimport)     int bitmap_buffer_size_x;
__declspec(dllimport)     int bitmap_buffer_size_y;
```

will the read/write acces thru

```
bitmap_bufer[bitmap_buffer_size_x*y + x]
```

will be slower? Im suspectiing thet probably it may be a bit slower
(probably acces thru two pointers than one) but im not sure

one would be bitmap_buffer pointer itself and teh second
would be pointer pointing to it (?)

If so it is sad as in relity one would be needed? Do someone knows more on this and could explain this?

Comment: If you want to speed up memory access, you need to properly align the data in memory. This has more impact on access performance than anything you mentioned in your question. See [alignas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn956970.aspx) and [_aligned_malloc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing data allocated in a dynamic library is not slower, as a matter of fact, `malloc` itself resides in a dynamic library.

Accessing an array through a global variable may be inefficient even if it is in the process data segment.  Store the pointer and the size into local variables and access the array this way:

```
char *bitmap = bitmap_bufer;
int pitch = bitmap_buffer_size_x;
int height = bitmap_buffer_size_y;

bitmap[y * span + x] = 0;
...
```

If you access pixels on a row-wise manner, use a pointer to the bitmap row:

```
char *row = bitmap + y * span;
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    row[x] = 1;
}
```

Also do not use `char` for pixel values, either use `unsigned char` for byte values between `0` and `UCHAR_MAX` or use `signed char` for values between `CHAR_MIN` and `CHAR_MAX`.  You might also use `int8_t` and `uint8_t` for clarity.  Reserve the type `char` for C strings.

Comment: well alright tnx for the hint on "Store the pointer and the size into local variables and access the array this way:" this is very good one -- but you seem anyway to contradict to yourself, sorta like speaking it is not a slower and then providing the trick to buffer it cliant side to get off  slowdown

Comment: I forgot to mention as i use 3 variables the cost would be potential 6 variable acces agains 3, so may be noticable waste - and i think it may be slower as dll data may be reallocked this acces to things like  bitmap_buffer_size_x; is not fixed like 0xfaceface but thru valee of a pointers which is at fixed adress and point to reallocked data (though im not sure as this may be maybe optimised away, i dont know)

Comment: @user2214913: I answered your question about *Efficiency of acces to array in dll*.  Efficiency of access to the memory does not depend on where it was allocated via `malloc()`, but it does depend on how you address it for individual accesses.  Using global variables for each access is potentially much slower than using local variables that may stay in registers across accesses.  Using direct pointers for row data may also help if the compiler cannot figure the access pattern on its own.

Comment: malock has not much to do, i think - more the thing the ram is a dll and Soma say for example calling function in a dll is a bit slower, wonder if same thing is if acces to array and variables

Comment: @user2214913: which part of my answer do you not understand?  Accessing data via global variable pointers is indeed slower than via local variables, especially if these global variables are dynamically resolved references in a separate DLL. It is a bad idea to do publish static data from a DLL anyway.  Calling a function in a DLL can be slower than a call to a statically linked function, and from my own experience, the overhead is even more important for data references, but it may depend on the OS version.

Comment: imo just global shouldnt be slower than local,  but global in dll might be slower (and i am asking if some can say maybe some more details on it) anyway this answer is ok - I publish static date becouse efficiency reason doubt if __declspec(dllexport) SetPixel(int x,int y, unsigned color) {bitmap_bufer[bitmap_buffer_size_x*y + x] = color} would be faster

Comment: than exporting static pointer (note i would need do millions of calls - i write sorta like per pixel drawing library as a dll) - this hint with "Store the pointer and the size into local variables" may help though - Do you think than with this hint acces will be slowet then as the buffer was on a client side or exacly equall? (hope it will be equal so it will be some cure at least for for some usage cases)

Comment: There is only one way to know: profiling the various alternatives.  If you incur a function call for each pixel you set in a trivial bitmap, at least make this an inline function that takes the bitmap buffer and size as arguments.